# Dynamic control access over class methods

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Consider the following case -

I have a class (Fruits), which has some methods such as PackTheFruit(), CutTheFruit(), CleanTheFruit(). This class can not be modified.

I also have a set of classes which would contain an object of fruit type. In some of the classes I want to have access to PackTheFruit() method but not in all.

I have thought creating two interfaces, which would be implemented by Fruits class. One would expose PackTheFruit() and one would expose the other methods only and each class would have an object of the these interface type instead depending on if they need to have access to that method or not.

The problem in this solution is that, when ever I add another method to the Fruits class I will have to update the interfaces. That would be a bad design in my eyes at least.

Comment: If you change an existing member signature or remove a member from an interface, then it is a breaking change; adding a member is non-breaking. I fail to see how your situation (adding more to the interface) is a bad design.

Comment: Well, changes are also possible. I dont want to keep updating my Interfaces.

Comment: Can I not control the method call by knowing who is calling it?

Comment: @m-y wanna bet. Read [Virtual Methods and Brittle Base Classes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2004/01/07/virtual-methods-and-brittle-base-classes.aspx) This would be especially bad if warning as error is turned on.

Comment: @ConradFrix: Interesting read... something to consider in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I depends what these operations are doing. Let's assume that packing consists of adding fruits to a basket up to a maximum weight, then you will need to know the weight of a fruit in order to make it packable. If you want to pack different kinds of fruits it would be better to have a separate packer class. It feels strange to have fruits packing themselves.

```
public interface IPackable
{
    public float Weight { get; set; }
}

public interface IPacker
{
    // Returns a list of packages represented by lists of fruits.
    List<List<Fruit>> GetPackages(IEnumerable<Fruit> fruits, float maxPackageWeight);
}

public class Packer : IPacker
{
    public List<List<Fruit>> GetPackages(IEnumerable<Fruit> fruits,
                                         float maxPackageWeight)
    {
        var currentPackage = new List<Fruit>();
        var packages = new List<List<Fruit>>(currentPackage);
        float currentWeight = 0.0f;
        foreach (Fruit fruit in fruits) {
            var packable = fruit as IPackable;
            if (packable != null && packable.Weight <= maxPackageWeight) {
                if (currentWeight + packable.Weight <= maxPackageWeight) {
                    currentPackage.Add(fruit);
                    currentWeight += packable.Weight;
                } else {
                    var currentPackage = new List<Fruit>(fruit);
                    packages.Add(currentPackage);
                    currentWeight = packable.Weight;
                }
            }
        }
        return packages;
    }
}
```

If you add new interfaces for new functionalities, you will not have to change existing interfaces. This is called [Interface segregation principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) (ISP) and is one of the five SOLID principles of Object-Oriented Design.

Note: Having an `IPacker` interface allows you to implement different kinds of packers. An implementation might mix different kinds of fruits within a package, while another one might sort the fruits.

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this?

```
class Fruit
{
    public float Weight { get; set; }   
}

interface IPackable { }

class Apple : Fruit, IPackable
{

}

class FruitPacker
{
    void Pack(IPackable fruit)
    {
        // pack fruit
    }
}
```

A fruit doesn't have to know *how* it's packed, so you won't have to implement that in the fruit.

Comment: I will update this in the question also, but the fruit class can not be modified.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your PackTheFruit(), CutTheFruit() and CleanTheFruit() methods should not be intrinsic to the Fruit class. The names sound like being done *with* a fruit but not *by* a fruit.

If you provide a FruitPacker class that knows how to pack a fruit you can provide an instance of this class to those of your classes that should be able to invoke that action. The same goes for the other methods.

Comment: could you explain it with an example please?

Comment: @TusharMathur he just wrote about the code in my post, see that for an example.